# Android How to implement services for time delayed actions?

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I implemented some app, that waits about some time before action. User can go to preferences and define time to wait. My problem is now that if I press home button I can´t start any other app, because my app take all resources. I have an motorloa milestone and my code is (part of source code of waiting service) :

```
 public void run() {
while(currentTime>waitingTime)
{ currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
  //do Action
}
```

It is an simple thread, but it seems to be very ineffective. I would be very thanks-full for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use `Handler` to schedule a `Message`. But your application needs to be in running state to get a call in Handler's callback mathod(`handleMessage(message)`). Another option is to go for `AlarmManger`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AlarmManager` to schedule a `PendingIntent` to be invoked at your designated time.